# Automate Alpine Linux installation

Tags: linux, system-installation, iso, alpine-linux

I am trying to achieve unattended Alpine Linux installation. I went through the Alpine [automatic installation guide](https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Installing/setup_alpine.html) but many manual interventions are still needed during the installation!
For example providing the root user name, creating the answer file (`setup-alpine -c answerfileName`), editing the answer file, calling the actual installation command (`setup-alpine -f answerfileName`) and resetting the root password.

Is there any way to include the answer file inside the ISO image, select the root user by default before starting the installation and set its password after the installation is done. In CentOS we can provide kickstart file in `isolinux.cfg`:

```
label MyMENU2
  menu label ^Deploy Manager Node
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=MYISO inst.ks=hd:LABEL=MYISO:/ks/ks1.cfg quiet
```

Is there something similar in Alpine Linux ?

Comment: I too looking for solution.

Comment: Is writing a small script to do the postinstall config not an option? Also there are various tools to simply edit iso's and add files, including an answerfile

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. but still even if I include the answer file into the ISO still we need to do the login and manually call the installation script ( by executing the setup-alpine command).

Comment: You can do a fully unattended install: https://wejn.org/2022/04/alpinelinux-unattended-install/, it just takes a bit of effort.

Answer (score 2):

Alpine has a service called `local`.

When this service start, it will execute all scripts named `*.start` found in `/etc/local.d/`.

But `local` service is not enabled by default.

Follow these Steps to enable `local` service, and let it execute our script:

1. write your installation script, save to `myscript.start`

   Reference: https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Installing/manual.html

   For example:

   ```
   # show script's output
   exec > >(tee -a /dev/tty0) 2>&1

   # delete this hack
   # otherwise this script will run on the system we newly installed
   rm -f /etc/local.d/myscript.start
   rm -f /etc/runlevels/default/local

   # do the system installation
   setup-interfaces -a
   rc-update add networking boot
   echo root:123@@@ | chpasswd
   printf '\nyes' | setup-sshd
   setup-keymap us us
   setup-timezone -i Asia/Shanghai
   setup-ntp chrony || true
   true >/etc/apk/repositories
   setup-apkrepos -1
   printf 'y' | setup-disk -m sys /dev/sda
   reboot
   ```
2. extract `initramfs-lts`. Need to do this in an empty folder

   ```
   zcat initramfs-lts | cpio -idm
   rm -f initramfs-lts
   ```
3. edit `init` file. find

   `exec switch_root $switch_root_opts $sysroot $chart_init "$KOPT_init" $KOPT_init_args`

   Add these 3 lines before the `exec` command:

   ```
   cp /myscript.start \$sysroot/etc/local.d/
   chmod a+x \$sysroot/etc/local.d/myscript.start
   ln -s /etc/init.d/local \$sysroot/etc/runlevels/default/
   ```
4. copy `myscript.start` to the same folder of `init` file
5. repack `initramfs-lts`

   ```
   find . | cpio -o -H newc | gzip -1 >initramfs-lts
   ```
6. replace `initramfs-lts` from iso to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

For a virtual machine, I wrote some code to automate the installation using directly the pristine .iso. Take a look at https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/ultrotter/alpine-autosetup for an initial proof of concept.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).